# Dúvida em Consulta SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Pessoal eu tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
--- mensagens
id
usuario_envia
usuario_recebe
texto
data_envio
```

Porém eu quero listar somente as "Conversas", por exemplo, quero que liste as mensagens agrupando elas com seus respectivos usuários que enviaram.

Na consulta `SELECT * FROM mensagens ORDER BY id` vai listar todas as mensagens, mas quero que liste por usuário que enviou. Obrigado.

Comment: SELECT * FROM mensagens WHERE usuario_envia = "id do usuario" ORDER BY id

Comment: Por exemplo se o usuario A enviou duas mensagens pro usuario B, com esta query vai listar estas duas mensagens, quero que liste apenas uma mensagem por usuario que enviou

Comment: entendi, to meio por fora, mas acho que colocando LIMIT 1 deve funcionar dessa forma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM mensagens GROUP BY usuario_envia
```

Comment: Caracas, era isso mesmo, to tão estressado que esqueci do GROUP BY. Obrigado.